# VBA, For-Loops not initiating?

Tags: vba, for-loop

I'm really confused as to why I have 2 For loops that aren't initiating. I have others in my macro that work fine, however. I even tried pulling the code sets out into different subs to see if the other code affected it, however it still didn't work! (This code worked fine yesterday... and the declarations are all correct (used elsewhere and reset fine).

One example:

```
         strVal = regionArr(counti, 3)
         For textSearch = 6 To lastrowVF
              If UCase(lesTab.Range("C" & textSearch).Text) Like UCase(strVal) & "*" Then
                 inTot.Range("K" & 2 + county).Value = lesTab.Range("C" & textSearch).Offset(0, 1).Value
                 inTot.Range("L" & 2 + county).Value = lesTab.Range("C" & textSearch).Offset(0, 2).Value
                 county = county + 1
              End If
         Next textSearch
```

Comment: Add a watch to `lastrowVF`. I'd bet my hat that it's less than 6.

Comment: What's the value of lasrowVF? How did you assign it a value? Also, textSearch needs to be udpated inside the loop so that the condition would eventually meet and the loop ends.

Comment: Wow, good call. Declaration accidentally got cut/pasted lower in the Sub and never noticed.